# Apply positive values to following rows until the value goes negative again

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with our current yearly demand forecast against the previous yearly demand forecast. This gives us how many parts we are saying we will need cumulatively each week of this year. This also gives us how many parts we previously said we will need cumulatively each week of the year. Finally, it tells us how many parts our supplier actually delivered to us between forecasts.

I take the previous forecasted quantity minus the quantity received and compare that against our new forecasted quantity. This tells us if we have increased demand between forecasts.

The problem is, if there is a positive demand change(which means they delivered more than we said we needed), then I need to apply that quantity to the following row. This needs to continue until that column goes negative again. In other words, if the difference between that row and the previous row ends up being positive, set that row to zero and apply the remaining balance to that same formula for the next row.

I have attached example data to show what I have and what I want. In addition, This is for many forecasts across many different part numbers. I could not think of a way to make a case statement work for this. I also thought about using a window function but could not think of a way to stop(or reset the balance being carried forward to 0) each time that column starts getting negative values.

| DataAP | Last Forecasted Demand | Delivered Quantity | New Forecasted Demand | Demand Change |  | Column I Need |  | remainder carried forward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2720 | 980 | 2170 | 430 |  | 0 |  | 430 |
| 2 | 3440 | 427 | 2845 | -168 |  | 0 |  | 262 |
| 3 | 4160 | 696 | 3520 | 56 |  | 0 |  | 318 |
| 4 | 4880 | NULL | 3970 | -910 |  | -592 |  | 0 |
| 5 | 5836 | NULL | 4956 | -880 |  | -880 |  | 0 |
| 6 | 6156 | NULL | 5356 | -800 |  | -800 |  | 0 |
| 7 | 7036 | NULL | 5756 | -1280 |  | -1280 |  | 0 |
| 8 | 7756 | NULL | 6876 | -880 |  | -880 |  | 0 |
| 9 | 8156 | NULL | 6876 | -1280 |  | -1280 |  | 0 |
| 10 | 8636 | NULL | 7836 | -800 |  | -800 |  | 0 |

SQL Template

```
SELECT
    SnapshotAP,
    DataAP,
    Plant,
    MaterialNumber,
    StartOfAPDemand,
    ReceiptQuantity,
    EndOfAPDemand,
    DemandChange AS DemandChange,
    LAG(DemandChange) OVER (PARTITION BY Plant, MaterialNumber, SnapshotAP ORDER BY DataAP) AS PreviousDemandChange,
-- Column used as divider in results in table
    '#' AS ______________________________,
-- Does not work because i can only add if previous row has positive remainder
    SUM(DemandChange) OVER (PARTITION BY Plant, MaterialNumber, SnapshotAP ORDER BY DataAP) AS CumulativeDemandChange,
FROM #IntermediateResults
```

Comment: If you post the DDL+DML (or a dbfiddle) with your sample data you'd make it a lot easier for people to assist. I for one would take a look.

Comment: Just to clarify, negative demand changes do not accumulate? That is, if the demand change goes -50, 50 then these do not net off, and the positive 50 should be carried over to the next row?

Comment: i think so, if im understanding you correctly. Basically, I need to snowplow all positive values forward, which will fill in any future negatives until there are not anything to plow forward. then the following results will remain unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a table has 2 columns, pk and d, where column 'pk' is a unique ordinal integer and column 'd' contains demand changes.  In the query below the case statement in the column 'case_logic' appears to produce the output you're looking for.

```
declare @T table (
    pk  int unique not null,
    d   int);

insert into @T(pk, d) values
(1, 430),
(2, -168),
(3, 56),
(4, -910), 
(5, -880),
(6, -800),
(7, -910),
(8, -880),
(9, -800),
(10, -910), 
(11, -880),
(12, -800);

select *, 
       sum(d) over (order by pk) sum_over,
       case when (sum(d) over (order by pk))>0 then 0 
            when abs(d)>abs(sum(d) over (order by pk)) then sum(d) over (order by pk) 
            else d end case_logic
from @t;
```

```
pk  d       sum_over    case_logic
1   430     430         0
2   -168    262         0
3   56      318         0
4   -910    -592        -592
5   -880    -1472       -880
6   -800    -2272       -800
7   -910    -3182       -910
8   -880    -4062       -880
9   -800    -4862       -800
10  -910    -5772       -910
11  -880    -6652       -880
12  -800    -7452       -800
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in all cases. If the first row was a negative demandChange then it should not be included in the running rum, but I think it will in the code you have provided. The tricky part of this problem is correctly partitioning the data set into over-supply "events" and not including demandChange values before that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any neat set-based way to do this, because it's really a recurrence relation - the carry-over you want to calculate is based on the same calculation being done on the previous rows. I think you therefore need to loop over the rows, either using a cursor, or with a recursive CTE like this:

```
-- ASSUMING THAT DataAP is a primary key - replace with the actual key if needed
-- Patitioning by Forecast_ID, Part_number - change to any columns you need 
-- BUT make sure that the join clause in the CTE matches the partition by columns
-- used to generate row_number
drop table if exists #IntermediateResults
Select *
,   [row_number] = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Forecast_ID, Part_number order by DataAP )
into #IntermediateResults
from (values
(   1,1,10,2720,980,2170,430    ),
(   2,1,10,3440,427,2845,-168   ),
(   3,1,10,4160,696,3520,56 ),
(   4,1,10,4880,NULL,3970,-910  ),
(   5,1,10,5836,NULL,4956,-880  ),
(   6,1,10,6156,NULL,5356,-800  ),
(   7,1,10,7036,NULL,5756,-1280 ),
(   8,1,10,7756,NULL,6876,-880  ),
(   9,1,10,8156,NULL,6876,-1280 ),
(   10,1,10,8636,NULL,7836,-800 ),
(   11,2,10,2756,999,2179,422   ),
(   12,2,10,3411,469,2849,-93   ),
(   13,2,10,4113,664,3493,44    ),
(   14,2,10,4893,NULL,3973,-920 ),
(   15,2,10,5859,NULL,4997,-862 ),
(   16,1,20,2725,1002,2142,419  ),
(   17,1,20,3467,445,2890,-132  ),
(   18,1,20,4192,717,3473,-2    ),
(   19,1,20,4893,NULL,3963,-930 ),
(   20,1,20,5861,NULL,4928,-933 )
) val(DataAP,Forecast_ID,Part_number,Last_Forecasted_Demand,Delivered_Quantity,New_Forecasted_Demand,Demand_Change)

;
with rcte as (
    Select 
        src.*
    ,   [counter] = 1
    ,   carry_over = case when Demand_Change > 0 then Demand_Change else 0 end
    ,   Column_I_Need = case when Demand_Change < 0 then Demand_Change else 0 end
    from #IntermediateResults src
    where [row_number] = 1
    union all
    select
        src.*
    ,   [counter] = new_counter
    ,   carry_over = case when sub_total > 0 then sub_total else 0 end
    ,   Column_I_Need = case when sub_total < 0 then sub_total else 0 end
    from rcte
    cross apply ( Select 
        new_counter = [counter] + 1
    ) calc1
    join #IntermediateResults src 
        on src.[row_number] = new_counter
        and src.Forecast_ID = rcte.Forecast_ID
        and src.Part_number = rcte.Part_number
    cross apply ( Select 
        sub_total = rcte.carry_over + src.Demand_Change
    ) calc2 
)
 select * from rcte
 order by DataAP
```

Comment: The loop_limit is confusing me. This table is for one forecast but my data has this same data for many different forecasts and part numbers(which are columns I excluded from my example). I would need this loop_limit to be unique for each partition by part_number and forecast

Comment: Hi @Maxwell - I've updated my answer to include some partition by columns. Let me know if this does the trick for you. You can change them to whatever columns you need, so long as the "partition by" statement at the top has the same columns as the join clause in the 2nd part of the CTE.
I've remove loop_limit since it was causing confusion. It wasn't really needed since we can rely on the inner join to stop the loop once the source data runs out.